# DB2 v11.5 FixPacks - anyone know when will they be released?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I don't see any FixPacks listed for DB2 v11.5.  We are considering its installation, but normally wait for a baseline correction before implementation.

Does anyone know if there is a FixPack in the works for DB2 v11.5 - and if so, when it will be released?

Answer (score 1):

Db2 11.5 ModPack 1, ModPack 2 and ModPack 3 (i.e. Db2 11.5.1.0, Db2 11.5.2.0 and Db2 11.5.3.0 respectively ) are available as a container only release

For example from

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c_whats_new_v11-5-1.html

> This mod pack release is currently available in the following Db2 products:

- The single container deployments of Db2 Warehouse and IBM Integrated Analytics System (IIAS)
- The container micro-service deployment of Db2 on Red Hat OpenShift
- The Db2 cartridge used by IBM Cloud Pak for Data

Similar statements are on the what's new pages for 11.5.2 and 11.5.3

See the main What's new page for information on container-only Db2 Mod Pack releases

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/r_whats_new_home.html

> IBM® offers a number of Db2-based solutions for small to enterprise
> size container environments [e.g., Db2 Community Edition, Db2
> Warehouse, the IBM Integrated Analytics System (IIAS)].
>
> These
> container-deployed products, and the Db2 engine that powers them, are
> released at regular intervals between traditional Db2 on-prem
> releases. The Db2 engine for these products is identified using the
> Mod Pack numbering scheme currently used in the Db2 product signature.
>
> New features that are available in these container-deployed Mod Pack
> releases are rolled into a subsequent Db2 on-prem release. The on-prem
> release also contains any new features that are available in the
> container-deployed release that aligns with its release date. So, each
> on-prem release of Db2 aligns with a similarly numbered
> container-ready release.

Container releases are available from the IBM Cloud Container Registry. E.g. for Db2 Warehouse, see the instructions here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCJDQ/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/get_image.html

The fixlist for Db2 11.5.1.0 and later releases can be found here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/fix-list-db2-version-115-linux-unix-and-windows

Comment: Thankyou for the pointers.  I've followed the links, but am still confused about the DB2 patching process.  I thought that a ModPack was made up of a set of FixPacks.  However, there aren't any FixPacks and the ModPack is a linux-only distribution.  Is this a valid indicator that there has been sufficient time since v11.5 availability to identify and fix any major issues?

Comment: A ModPack just means that the modification number has been increased. This indicates new features as well as fixes. When only the FixPack number increases, then that indicates no new features.  E.g. 11.1.4.5 is just fixes when compared to 11.1.4.4

Comment: Personally, I'm not sure that using "sufficient time since GA" is a particularly meaningful or sophisticated approach to assessing what and when to upgrade. Just one of many factors is how much new/changed functionality there is in a product in the areas that you are looking to exploit and how important those features are to you. All software has bugs (so they say), and there is no substitute for testing things in your own environment, no matter if you are taking a new version, new release, new modification or new fixpack.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but I cannot find a regular 11.5.1.0 release on docker hub. The only existing one is for OpenShift only and is a completely different image to 11.5.0.0, so we cannot upgrade to this version. Did any of you find the regular 11.5.1.0 image?

Comment: As mentioned on the ModPack site https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/vi/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0070229.html#c0070229__section_rjf_1tk_4jb the container download is available only using passport advantage. But I cannot find any link to download it using passport advantage. Did any of you find the container download on passport advantage?

Comment: I've updated the links and copied content. If a customer wants a fix that is only currently available in a container only release, they would need to raise that request with support if they do not/cannot wait until the next on-premise fixpack release.

Comment: @PaulVernon  Thanks. I dislike having to raise a support ticket just to get an on-premises fixpack. IBM needs to fix this! Some customers do not dockerize their Db2 estate.

Comment: The next on prem fixpack is not far away.  As I understand things (and I'm nowhere near being a maker of such decisions) the idea of the container only releases is that the consuming products such as Db2 Warehouse etc have a faster life cycle, and want/need more frequent releases. On prem typically want fewer releases (and, the implication being maybe more stable releases), so only every 3rd or 4th mod level would come out on prem.   If you have specific issues and need a specifc fix, then support can help. But not sure if they would give you a full container only fixpack for on prem install

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Db2 11.1

> Db2® uses a four part product signature that includes both Modification Pack values (Mod Pack) and Fix Pack values."

The product signature format follows the Maintenance Delivery Vehicle standard  (http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008656) that is used throughout the IBM® product lines.

> The IBM® product signature The Db2 four part product signature is of
>   the format VV.RR.MM.FF where:
>
> ```
> VV Is the Version number.
> RR Is the Release number.
> MM Is the Modification number.
> FF Is the Fix Pack number.
> ```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0070229.html#c0070229